# How to make drupal 6 support Master-Slave MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, drupal-6

Is there any solutions in Drupal 6 to split query READ to Slave and WRITE to Master ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Pressflow](http://fourkitchens.com/pressflow-makes-drupal-scale), which is a derivative of Drupal geared towards scaling in high-traffic.

It has support for replication in MySQL among other features.

I have no direct experience, just know of it and thought it might be of interest to you.